# Actionscript 3: How to add an on-the-fly-created-movieclip into datagrid?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I need to create a movieclip on the fly by coding, and then put it into datagrid.
Can anyone help me? I'll write the detail below.

On https://stackoverflow.com/a/2035638/1201144, thanks to George Profenza for providing an answer.
His answer can add predefined movieclip from library into the datagrid.
But I need to inherit that mc dynamically, then put tem into datagrid.
This is George's answer

> import fl.controls.DataGrid;
>   import fl.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;
>   import fl.data.DataProvider;
>   
>   var dp:DataProvider = new DataProvider();
>   //populate the provider, specifying the source (linkageID and frame of the clip to display)
>   for(var i:int = 0 ; i < 7; i++)
>       dp.addItem({data:{source:**'Star'**,frame:i+1}, title:"clip Star at frame"+(i+1)+""});
>   var dataCol:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("data");
>   dataCol.cellRenderer = ClipCell;
>
> var titleCol:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("title");
>
> var myDataGrid:DataGrid = new DataGrid();
>   myDataGrid.addColumn(dataCol);
>   myDataGrid.addColumn(titleCol);
>   myDataGrid.dataProvider = dp;
>   myDataGrid.rowHeight = 64;
>   myDataGrid.width = 500;
>   myDataGrid.rowCount = dp.length - 1;
>   addChild(myDataGrid);

Object Star was already designed in the library.
Let's say I need to inherit the 'Star' to 'LittleStar' and 'BigStar'. Then attach them to datagrid? The first row for littleStar and second row for the bigStar.
I have tried like:

> var LittleStar:Star = new Star();
>   dp.addItem({data:{source:'LittleStar',frame:i+1}, title:"clip Star at frame"+(i+1)+""});

But I got error that LittleStar was not defined. What should I do?
Note: George has inherited ClipCell class from iCellRenderer. And use it to his datagrid.

Comment: I would really appreciate for @GeorgeProfenza to help me out.<br> Or anyone?

Comment: 1- Make a class that contains all DataGrid implementations and functionality. 2- Simply add an instance of that class on your events (like mouse click) inside your main application. 3- Have an eye on Garbage Collection from memory.

Comment: You need something like 'var newGrid = new myGridData();' which myGridData() is the name of class that makes all datagrid for you.

Comment: `LittleStar` is not a class, it's the name of a variable holding a reference on an object of type `Star`. When it is time to create objects from the information stored in the data provider, then `ClipCell` is trying to create an object from the class with the name stored on `source`. This cannot work for `LittleStar` because there is no such class defined as you expected by `var LittleStar:Star = new Star();`. What you want is generating new classes on runtime, but I guess that cannot be done (so easy) in Flash/ActionScript. But check whether the keywords _ByteArray_ and _AMF_ will help you.