# How to set scaleX scaleY to a particular row in the advanced datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

Is that possible to give scaleX scaleY to a particular row in the advanced datagrid.I am having an advanced datagrid in that i used separate itemrenderers for each column.Now the requirement is from the rows one particular row should be effectable like scalex.I searched in google i didnt find any solution for this instead i found how to set rowbackground color but i need some scale effect to one particular row other than the selected row.
Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: one of the solution: - You can create BitMap image of particular cell/row and zoom that on top of it.

Comment: If i keep a bitmap image then what abt the data which i kept in the hgroup inside the itemrenderer.Thanks for ur reply

Answer (score 1):

For your problem you need to add child display object in the datagrid cell (as a item) and you have to put the your data in the particular display object. and you can apply scaling on the display object which is render as a child of cell.

directly you can't apply the scaling to the cell ...of data grid.

Please refer this answer for [code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395016/add-movieclips-and-controlling-them-in-a-datagrid-in-as)

Another Example for the same : [Click Here](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?307322-Attach-Movieclip-to-Datagrid-Cell-%28and-detect-mouse-click-on-cellRenderer%29)

UI component or any other display object which is rendered as cell item, pleat apply scaling on it

Comment: Murgesh thanks for ur reply.I didnt understand ur answer clearly. can you please give me some example

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to override the renderer and add a custom style to it. When that style gets a value, use that value to set the scaleX, scaleY. You can then use styleFunction on the ADG to set that value.  You can see the concept demonstrated [here](http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2008/09/extended-datagrid-with-stylefunction.html), using my DataGrid_withStyleFunction Class, where I added styleFunction on top of DataGrid.